# LPK9-4P PSU 12V output not working

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics

I have an old PSU, model LPK9-4P. I'm trying to power an Arduino project with it, but it doesn't work as expected.

PSU is wired with a switch between signal and ground, and powers on well. Measures shows voltage in every line. But 12V line, with just 2 fans on it, just works few seconds before falling down.

5V line is stable and working, powering arduino and a bunch of sensors.

Is this about load requirements?  A malfunctioning PSU?  I'm kind of stuck with it, and it's just a testing power source!

[image: Photo of PSU label]

<sub>[Photo original on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9zqdJulDgw1UmhrdmlZZHVpTVU/view?usp=drivesdk)</sub>
The photo is the only data I have about this psu.

Comment: What does the data sheet for the power supply tell you? No data sheet = no help unfortunately.

Comment: Have you connected the PS_on Line to ground? the green wire in the ATX harness.

Comment: Yes, it's connected with a switch to easily on/off.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9zqdJulDgw1UmhrdmlZZHVpTVU/view?usp=drivesdk this is the only data I have about this psu. I can't find nothing online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] 12V line, with just 2 fans on it, just works few seconds before falling down.
>
> 5V line is stable and working, powering arduino and a bunch of sensors.
>
> Is this about load requirements?

It is impossible to be *sure* without a proper datasheet. However, this *might* be the problem, because some PC PSUs do require a minimum load on their +12V rail for correct operation. The two fans you mention as the only load on the +12V rail, would not meet the minimum load requirements for some of the PSUs which I have seen.

Without whatever minimum load a specific PSU requires, the +12V rail may fluctuate or may even rise enough to trigger over-voltage protection, and other rails (including the +5V rail) may also be out of regulation.

To test this possibility, connect a car headlight bulb (e.g. 50-60W) to the +12V rail to draw around 5A and see if the bulb remains lit. If it does remain lit, then that confirms your specific PSU requires a minimum +12V load.

Update: Of course, another possibility is that your PSU has an internal fault.

Comment: Tried. And it doesn't work, same problem. Thanks for the tip, I will keep in mind to test future scavenged psu's